# Adding Azimuth to each point in GeoJSON

Tags: openlayers, geojson, style, azimuth, rotate

I have a GeoJSON which returns a set of points, for each point I have different azimuth(rotation) is required.

I have tried using the `rotate` property of OpenLayers, however when I use it all the point in the GeoJSON are getting rotated to the angle defined.

```
t.setStyle(
      new ol.style.Style({
          image: new ol.style.Icon({
              src: "/Icons/signal.png",
              anchor: [ 0, 0.5 ],
              rotation: 0,
              scale: [ 0.35, 0.35 ]
          }),
      })
   );
```

Instead, I want to rotate each point in GeoJSON at a different angle by the azimuth value which I have.

Could someone suggest me a solution for this?

Comment: I guess you mean you want to rotate **the symbol** shown at each point?

Comment: Use a style function to set the rotation, based on a property of the feature, for each point, as in https://jsfiddle.net/hbka547j/